# equal and not equal

Tags: mysql

I have this `mysql` query which works in getting the specific data by specified date;

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE DAY(idate)='11' AND MONTH(idate)='01' AND YEAR(idate)='2013' GROUP BY id
```

now i want to get the data from the date specified and the data outside the date specified, I've tried this query and returns zero results;

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE DAY(idate)='11' AND DAY(idate)<>'11' AND MONTH(idate)='01' AND YEAR(idate)='2013' GROUP BY id
```

Comment: uhmm create a calendar table and create `LEFT JOIN` from it.

Comment: What does it mean "get the data from the date specified and the data outside the date specified"?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i think he wants to get zero result which from 1 to 30 of the month, except 11.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE DAY(idate)='11' AND DAY(idate)<>'11' 
                       AND MONTH(idate)='01' AND YEAR(idate)='2013' GROUP BY id
```

is saying "Select the id for the rows from mytable where the day is both equal to 11 and also not equal to 11..."

This is an impossible situation, hence you're getting nothing.

What you *actually* want is "Select the id for the rows from mytable where the day is equal to 11 as well as the rows where date is not equal to 11...", I think. This is the same as "Select the id for the rows from mytable regardless of the value of the date..." or:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE MONTH(idate)='01' AND YEAR(idate)='2013' GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable t1
WHERE DAY(idate)<>'11'
  OR ( DAY(idate) = '11' 
      AND MONTH(idate)='01' 
      AND YEAR(idate)='2013' 
    )
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: @downvoter, Please care to explain? What is the problem in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use your first query and [subtract](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,236210,236210) from the queried table, or you can fix your query (read about [De-Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
SELECT id
    FROM mytable 
         WHERE DAY(idate)<>'11' OR MONTH(idate)<>'01' OR MONTH(idate)='01' OR YEAR(idate)='2013'
 GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query at the moment basically has this as a WHERE clause:

```
where 1 = 1
and   1 <> 1
```

Obviously both cannot be true.  Similarly your filters on `DAY(idate)` are mutually exclusive.  It is difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.  Perhaps you should jyst remove the tests on DAY() altogether?

```
SELECT id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE MONTH(idate)='01' 
AND YEAR(idate)='2013' 
GROUP BY id
```